# Wrapping a function's arguments

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

I am trying to figure out the mechanism to transform a generic function with *n* arguments into a function where each of the *n* argument is wrapped inside a context.

A simple example in pseudo-Haskell, where the wrapped type is tuple:

```
wrap :: (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> ...) -> Context c -> ((c, a1) -> (c, a2) -> (c, a3) -> ...)
```

The container which holds the contexts is suggested by the alias `Context c`, for which I'm yet to figure out a reasonable form. For example it could be an n-tuple, a list of `c`s or even a composition of type `(c -> c -> c -> ...)`.

It would most likely have to do with some ingenious use of applicative functors or monads, but I currently have no idea where to start attacking the problem. Any lead would be deeply appreciated.

**Edit. Resolution**

As the comments below suggest, the behaviour can be described as "give me some generic function with *n* arguments and [some contexts] and attach a context to each argument of the function". This resulting function will be applied applicative-style to *n* structures `S a` using some operators which are implemented to make use of these contexts, something like:

```
(wrap f contexts) §> s1 <§> s2 <§> s3 <§> ....
```

As an example, I got something running with [fixed-size vectors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parameterized-data-0.1.5) arguments like `FSVec c a`. So I was wondering whether there is a method to pass a generic function of type `fi :: [a1] -> [a2] -> ...` and some lengths and "zip" them to get `fo :: FSVec c a1 -> FSVec c a2 -> ...`. And even more, can it be done in a generic way, i.e. apply any arbitrary constructor, not necessarily one which uses type-level (e.g. a tuple constructor as in the example above)?

**Alternate solution**

Of course, I can always "zip" the contexts on the structures themselves, having to only reimplement `(§>)` and `(<§>)` to act accordingly and saving me a lot of trouble:

```
f §> (c1, s1) <§> (c2, s2) <§> (c3, s3) <§> ...
```

Still, I would like to "hide" these contexts as to separate concerns. Apart from just being a matter of style, it is actually a good mental exercise to explore the power of applicative functors and applicative-like functions.

Comment: right now the `...` part will be the worst concern - so you should start by trying to figure out the type-signature (IMO this will not primary be a monad or applicative problem - it's more like a type-function problem right now) - so the first question: is this supposed to work for `a -> b` and `a -> b -> c`, ... or for some fixed arity?

Comment: I think it's worth elaborating on the situation you're in where you feel like you need this. It reminds me a bit of the `Reader` monad, but it's subtly different, I suppose.

Comment: Also, it is always easier to write a series of functions `wrapC wrapC2 wrapC3`... à la `liftA` and `liftM`. You can throw yourself into a type-function mess, but consider if it's really worth it. You probably don't need to wrap anything bigger than a six-argument function.

Comment: Your `wrap` currently says "give me a function and n tuples and I'll apply this function to second projections of these tuples". It's simply `f <$> t1 <*> t2 <*> t3 <*> ...`. Do you actually want the opposite — "give me a function that receives n tuples and give me n arguments and I'll attach a context to each argument and apply the function"?

Comment: @user3237465: the second situation is exactly what I was expecting. Indeed, I got the idea from studying how applicative functors work and checking the instance implementation for `((->)r)`. I imagine an operator that works on every `r` in a composition `r -> r -> ...`, similar to how `(<*>)` behaves.

Comment: @Lynn : I will try to elaborate the question then, and will also check how `Reader` works.